# Easiest Method for determining Active Directory groups and members in SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, active-directory

I need to write a report in SSRS (T-SQL) that shows any current user which reports on the SSRS report server they have read-access to, which is determined by Active Directory at the present. To complicate matters, the Active Directory doesn't have groups set up as group elements - all users in the AD are objectClass=User and objectCategory=Person.

My question is: how can I write a query that will match a user to all their "memberOf" elements without knowing necessarily what the group names are (since they might change, etc.)? From there, I think I can piece together how to match each element to the reports.

EDIT: Here's what I have written so far. It's not creating the procedure because of a syntax error, but I can't spot the error.

```
USE [ReportServer]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ActiveDirectoryPermissions]
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    [GroupName] nvarchar(MAX),
    [GroupPath] nvarchar(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 ( [GroupName], [GroupPath] )
    SELECT sAMAccountName as [GroupName], replace(ADsPath,'LDAP://','') as [GroupPath]
        FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI,
        'SELECT sAMAccountname, ADsPath
        FROM ''LDAP://DC=[REDACTED],DC=COM''
        WHERE objectCategory=''group'' AND CN=''*''
        ORDER BY CN')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    [GroupPath] nvarchar(MAX),
    [MemberName] nvarchar(MAX)
)

DECLARE table_1_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT GroupPath
    FROM @Table1 t1

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @temp nvarchar(MAX)

OPEN table_1_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM table_1_cursor INTO @temp

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT '''+@temp+''' AS GroupPath, cn 
        FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,
        ''SELECT cn 
        FROM ''''LDAP://DC=[REDACTED],DC=com''''
        WHERE
        memberOf='''''+@temp+'''''
        '')'
    INSERT INTO @Table2 ( [GroupPath], [MemberName] )
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_1_cursor INTO @temp
END

CLOSE table_1_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_1_cursor

SELECT *
FROM @Table2 t2
INNER JOIN @Table1 t1 ON (t2.GroupPath=t1.GroupPath)

GO
```

Comment: I've added the current code that refuses to compile because of a syntax error, but I can't find the error.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15 ,State 1, Procedure ActiveDirectoryPermissions, Line 56 [Batch Start Line 8]
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Yeah. Caught the missing "END" right before I read this. *derp* And ADSI is the linked server that exposes AD, yes. This should work now. Thank you for your help, Mike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the contents of the stored procedure and create it. Then alter the sproc by uncommenting the statements one at a time. You can also try commenting out parts of the select statement. I suspect the problem is where you are building @ sql. I would select @ temp and @ sql at this point. Running the code directly rather than as part of a a procedure. That way you can manually check and test the output. Well done for persevering this far. Those ' would have driven me mad.

You are missing the final END on the stored procedure. Next problem: What is ADSI ? I presume that is the name of a linked server that exposes AD? As in

[https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/](http://example%20of%20accessing%20AD%20from%20SQL%20Server)

There is an alternative method of accessing AD that does not require the linked server.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_QueryAD   
    'SELECT sAMAccountname, ADsPath
    FROM ''LDAP://OU=REDACTED,DC=REDACTED''
    WHERE objectCategory=''group'' AND CN=''*''
    ORDER BY CN'
```

There is a small amount of config to enable this, but if you search on the error, it only takes a moment to set up.